# UIImageVIew keep coming forward in TableViewCell (using swift, Xcode)

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform, uiimageview

I'm trying to build an app using UITableViewController. I set a UIImageView inside the UITableViewCell.

I've managed to show the image. But, I still can't manage the image to stay at back.

I already use command Editor >> Arrange >> Send to Back, in storyboard, but it's not working.

I also tried this code : `cell.sendSubviewToBack(cell.photo)`
, but still got the same problem.

can someone help me with this?

FYI, I used ParseUI SDK from [parse.com](http://parse.com)

here is my whole code :

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var searchBar: UISearchBar!


    // Initialise the PFQueryTable tableview
    override init(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
        super.init(style: style, className: className)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        // Configure the PFQueryTableView
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
        self.paginationEnabled = true
    }

    // Define the query that will provide the data for the table view
    override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {

        // Start the query object
        var query = PFQuery(className: "Places")

        // query with pointer
        query.includeKey("mainPhoto")

        // Add a where clause if there is a search criteria
        if searchBar.text != "" {
            query.whereKey("name", containsString: searchBar.text)
        }

        // Order the results
        query.orderByAscending("name")

        // Return the qwuery object
        return query
    }


    //override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject) -> PFTableViewCell? {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tableCell") as! CustomTableViewCell!
        if cell == nil {
            cell = CustomTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "tableCell")
        }

        // Extract values from the PFObject to display in the table cell
        if let name = object["name"] as? String{
            cell.name.text = name
        }

        if let detail = object["address"] as? String{
            cell.detail.text = detail
        }

        // display initial image
        var initialThumbnail = UIImage(named: "question")
        cell.photo.image = initialThumbnail
        cell.photo.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center

        // extract image from pointer
        if let pointer = object["mainPhoto"] as? PFObject {
            if let thumbnail = pointer["photo"] as? PFFile {
                cell.photo.file = thumbnail
                cell.photo.loadInBackground()
                cell.photo.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
                cell.sendSubviewToBack(cell.photo)
            }
        }

        // return the cell
        return cell
    }


    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].

        var detailScene = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController

        // Pass the selected object to the destination view controller.
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            let row = Int(indexPath.row)
            detailScene.currentObject = objects[row] as? PFObject
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:Selector("hideKeyboard"))
        tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = true
//        tableView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

    func hideKeyboard(){
        tableView.endEditing(true)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        // Refresh the table to ensure any data changes are displayed
        tableView.reloadData()

        // Delegate the search bar to this table view class
        searchBar.delegate = self
    }

    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

        // Dismiss the keyboard
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()

        // Force reload of table data
        self.loadObjects()
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

        // Dismiss the keyboard
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()

        // Force reload of table data
        self.loadObjects()
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

        // Clear any search criteria
        searchBar.text = ""

        // Dismiss the keyboard
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()

        // Force reload of table data
        self.loadObjects()
    }


}
```

Comment: What do you want the image view to be back of? What is your view hierarchy?